# Reading a text file and creating two types of objects, but the first object type is created twice

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an object 'liman', liman contains ships and containers in ArrayLists. I'm trying to fill the ArrayLists from a text file which goes like this:

> 1574683 Abyssinia 
>   8546279 Royal_Oak 
>   2454438 Oceanway 
>   9146578 Atilgan 
>   3378841 Albatros 
>   6562152 Imbat
>
> 1000085321 N N 
>   1000255963 N N 
>   1000511926 N N 
>   1000853210 N N 
>   1001279815 N N 
>   1001791741 N N 
>   1002388988 N N 
>   ...

This file has 6 ships, their IMOs and their names. It has 624 containers, their serial numbers and two features. Here's my method:

```
public static Liman readK( Liman liman){
    Scanner inputFileReader = null;
    try {

        inputFileReader = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Asus\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\NesneProjesi\\src\\\\liman.txt"));
        String line;
        String[] lineCutter;

        while (inputFileReader.hasNextLine()){
            line = inputFileReader.nextLine();

            if(line.length() > 7){
                lineCutter = line.split(" ");
                if(lineCutter[0].length()== 7){ //trying to see if the line contains a ship

                    int imo = Integer.valueOf(lineCutter[0]);
                    String isim = lineCutter[1];
                    Gemi yeniGemi = new Gemi(imo,isim);
                    liman.Gemiler.add(yeniGemi);
                } else if(lineCutter[0].length() == 10){//trying to see if the line contains a container

                    long ser= Long.valueOf(lineCutter[0]);
                    String Konteyner_Ozelligi= lineCutter[1];
                    String Icerik_Ozelligi= lineCutter[2];
                    Konteyner yeniKonteyner = new Konteyner(ser,Konteyner_Ozelligi,Icerik_Ozelligi);
                    liman.Lkonteynerler.add(yeniKonteyner);
                }
             }
         }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //System.out.println(liman.Lkonteynerler);
        inputFileReader.close();
        return liman;
    }
}
```

This code creates containers and adds them to the liman's ArrayList for containers. It's the same for the ships, but it creates the ships twice. So the size of liman's ArrayList for ships is 12. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you debug your code?

Comment: It gets the ships, and then it goes back and gets it again. After that, it continues to the containers.

Comment: Your code reads the ships correctly when I run it on my machine (it finds 6 ships as expected). Are you sure that the `Liman` object you're passing in to `readK` doesn't already have ships in it? You can test this by adding `System.out.println(liman.Gemiler.size());` as the first line of `readK`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention. I just solved the problem.